# AWS - SQS deletionPolicy on specific custom exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, queue, amazon-sqs

In AWS sqs i need to consider message as failed and retry it only on specific custom exception rather than on all runtime exception

```
    @SqsListener(value = "/MyQueueURL", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS )
    public void getMessageFromSqs(MyMessage message) {
        
        log.info("message: {}", message);

        // Ignore other exceptions

        if(somecondition) {
            throw new MyCustomException("Retry it"); //<--- Fail only on this exception
        }
        
        log.info("Success");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to use java try catch block, to hide the other errors.   Although this concept does seem risky as ANY coding error you could lose data.

Since the deletion policy is on success it will automatically remove message from SQS.

```
@SqsListener(value = "/MyQueueURL", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS )
public void getMessageFromSqs(MyMessage message) {
  try {      
    log.info("message: {}", message);

        // Ignore other exceptions

        if(somecondition) {
            throw new MyCustomException("Retry it"); //<--- Fail only on this exception
        }
        
        log.info("Success");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.info("error")
        if (e instanceOf MyCustomException) {
          throw e
        }
    }
}
```